# Create time and date stamp in specific cell using column and row indexes

Tags: excel, vba

I have predefined functions that finds the column and row indexes of the cell I want to enter the time/date stamp at, however when I run the code I get a `Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed` error at line `With SDtab.Range(SDrev_rowindex, formula)`. When debugging I can see that variables `SDrev_rowindex` and `formula` both are set to the correct index, so I am not sure why I will not print the time and date stamp. If I replace `SDrev_rowindex` and `formula` with `"K4"` which is the cell the two indexes are referring to it works fine. Here is my code:

```
Public Sub Main()
Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, dict As Object, sysrow As Integer, sysnum As String, wsName As String, wbSrc As Workbook, SDtab As Worksheet
Dim spectyp As Long, specmin As Long, specmax As Long, formula As Long
Dim cell As Range, startcell As String

For Each cell In ws.Range(startcell, ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, syswaiver).End(xlUp)).Cells 
    sysnum = cell.Value
    sysrow = cell.Row
    syscol = cell.Column

formula = getcolumnindex(SDtab, "Formula / step size")

' SD Revision Section
SDrev_rowindex = getrowindex(sysnum, "SD Revision", "Test-Config-OCT")

With SDtab.Range(SDrev_rowindex, formula) ' "K4"
    .Value = Now()
    .NumberFormat = "h:mm:ss:AM/PM   mm/dd/yyyy"
End With
```

Next cell

End Sub

Comment: Try `With SDtab.Cells(SDrev_rowindex, formula)`. I've done this many times.

Comment: @VBasic2008 Ugh of course its something as simple as that to get me stuck - thank you!!